# owncloud on ubuntu

Tags: cloud

i have installed owncloud on ubuntu but i can find it on the menu dash, i even try to run own terminal by typing owncloud, but nothing start

i also have an ubuntu 1 account but i also would like to use owncloud

can i use owncloud on ubuntu?

our do i have to be with kde to use owncloud?

or do i have to install another package?
i have install owncloud from synaptic

i am using ubuntu 12.04 beta

Comment: OwnCloud working pretty fine over here, please provide information about your install. How did you install it? If you set it on your www folder simply go to your web browser and try http://localhost/cloud (change "clound" for whatever the name of your cloud folder is), if you used another method please let us know in order to help you. My Ubuntu Web Server OwnCloud demo can be reached right here: http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/cloud use "guest" as user and "demo" as password (without quotes, this  account will be erased soon). Waiting for your information. Thank you.

Comment: i have installed using synaptic

Comment: how do you start owncloud?

Comment: OwnCloud is using PHP5 and MySQL services for a web interface, it should be used by installing it as a web service. Usually placed on /var/www but these services are mostly installed into their proper folders which may difficult to find how to call it from the browser. I simply downloaded the compressed file, unzipped, and placed its contents on my www folder, deleted the "data" folder inside the "cloud" folder and called it from a web browser. I named it "cloud" so you can reach it with that link. I usually reach it via http://localhost/cloud and it works.

Comment: OwnCloud seems not to be a program but a web service, so you won't find a way to run it as a program or GUI. I suggest you to give a chance downloading the compressed file and moving it to your /var/www folder, then call it via web browser and run the install. 0770 permissions are required in order to run install, MySQL or any compatible database is also required. After all, everything seems to be easy and the install runs like a charm.

Comment: i manage to get it.but the service is online or is it provide on my local system?and the maximum of space that i can upload is 2mb

Comment: The service is provided by your own local system and will be online only if your computer is turned on, bandwidth depends on your ISP connection and the maximum space that you can use for online storage is defined by the limit of your hard disk drive or quota, depending what you specify for each user. The maximum file size that I can upload is 512mb, as mentioned in the popup when I hover the "upload button". Maybe something is different in your server/setup which may lead to limit the upload's filesize. If you wish let's talk later in the chat later, (3 hours aprox)

Comment: If you agree I can make a resume of all this in order to place it as an answer so you can upvote it/accept if this has helped you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is a [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) that provides hosted services including [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldav) (calendar), [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) (Files), and [CardDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV) (address book) services.

Because OwnCloud provides the services which are consumed by the client PC, it is generally installed on a server, although some do run OwnCloud locally.

Since you installed OwnCloud on your PC, you automatically also installed (due to OwnCloud dependencies) the [Apache server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache2), which is probably already running on your computer.

If you decide that you want to keep OwnCloud running on your local pc, you should be able to access it through your browser at this url: http://localhost/owncloud

Files of interest if you decide to keep and configure the software:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/owncloud.conf
/var/lib/owncloud/config/config.sample.php
```

Sources:

```
apt-file list owncloud
```

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/owncloud/oneiric/view/head:/debian/owncloud.install

Comment: it is fantastic, by the way :) I use it on my VPS and love it. Since it has fairly low requirements, you might even be able to run it on a shared web host, though I haven't tried it.