# How can I run owncloud?

Tags: owncloud-server

I am getting a weird error from owncloud, and the documentation isn't helping nor are the forum topics.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 but that shouldn't affect anything (nothing different between it and 13.04 that should cause this).

[image]

What is this config directory and what do I need to do to give owncloud access?

Comment: Did you used the Ubuntu package or build from source?

Comment: I used the Ubuntu package from the Open Suse build service. I've run into another issue now so I will open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around on a link I found on [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116571/owncloud-on-ubuntu), I discovered that in newer versions the (***undocumented***) config folder is actually `/etc/owncloud`.